# MS Azure backup failing to backup new versions of files

Tags: azure, backup

We are using MS Azure Backup to backup our files from a specific folder on a local disk to an Azure backup service however it is not updating the cloud version of some files when they have been updated locally.

The errlog has recorded a number of the following errors
Failed: Hr: = [0x80070005] : CreateFile failed \?\Volume{...}\ with error :5

More worryingly the jobs in question on the jobs list show successful with no indication of any issues.
I only discovered this because 1 job from 3 days ago was tagged as having warning which appears to be a connectivity issue somewhere and came across these entries in the log.

Would someone be able to

1. Indicate how we can get these changed files to be backed up?
2. Answer why the MS Azure Backup jobs are listed as successful when these warnings have been recorded?

Thanks
Gavin

Answer (score 0):

It seems like there is a permission issue to the files and folders which you are tying to backup to Azure. Please check if the folders or the drive you are backing up is formatted in NTFS.

Thanks

Hope this help.